# How to adjust the width of an input text in angular

Tags: angular

How to adjust the width of an input text in angular

I have an input text component from another library, called 'njm-input'.
In my app, I'd like to use it and adjust its width.
First, I put it in my flexbox div and the width of the div is 20% of the line.
Then, I'd like to set the width of 'njm-input' to '100px'.
What I've done didn't work. [The online sample is here](http://plnkr.co/edit/dkrCYh?p=preview).

src/app.ts

```
import {Component, NgModule, VERSION} from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'
import {NmjInputComponent} from './component/nmj-input'
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
      <div class="grid">
        <div class="grid-cell u-1of10">
          <label>name:</label>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-cell u-1of2">
          <nmj-input></nmj-input>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  `,
  styles: [`
    .grid {
      display: flex;
    }
    .grid-cell {
      flex: 1;
    }
    .grid-cell.u-1of10 {
      flex: 0 0 10%;
      text-align: right;
      background-color: red;
    }
    .grid-cell.u-1of2 {
      flex: 0 0 20%;
      border: 1px red solid;
    }

    .nmj-input {
      width: 100px;
    }
  `],
})
export class App {
  name:string;
  constructor() {
    this.name = `Angular! v${VERSION.full}`
  }
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ App, NmjInputComponent ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

src/component/nmj-input.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'nmj-input',
  template: `
  <input type="text" class='form-control'>
  `,
  styles: [`
    :host { width: 100%; }
    .form-control { width: 100%; }
  `],
})
export class NmjInputComponent {
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Make use of `ViewEncapsulation`

```
import { Component,ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'nmj-input',
  template: `
  <input type="text" class='form-control'>
  `,
  styles: [`
    :host { width: 100%; }
    .form-control { width: 100%; }
  `],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None // added to component
})
export class NmjInputComponent {
```

}

**In the Parent Component**

Add this to css

```
:host /deep/ .form-control{
  background: darkkhaki;
  width:100px;
}
```

Working [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/SUTXtx?p=preview)

You can get a working example and more explanation on the same here 
[Link](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/#/host)

Comment: NmjInputComponent  isn't mine. So I couldn't modify it.

Comment: even keeping `:host {
  width: 100%;
}` in the nmjinput css wont changeanything you can still make use of the same